# Debugging a QueryTables.Add script

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

```
Sub FindData()

Dim accountNumber As Range
Set accountNumber = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Dim dataSet As QueryTable

For Each Value In accountNumber
    Set dataSet = .QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="URL;http://www.prad.org/CamaDisplay.aspx?OutputMode=Display&SearchType=RealEstate&ParcelID=" & Value, _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1"))
    Next Value

With dataSet
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = "3"
End With

With Application
    dataSet.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

The ultimate goal here is to pull data from the `URL` and drop it into `Worksheet(2)`. The values in `accountNumber` go at the end of the `URL` for each page to draw data from.

This is my first VBA script, and right off the bat, it's giving me an error on `Sub FindData()`

I have the table of accountNumbers. The URL for one account is the given URL with an accountNumber after the final =. I am trying to iterate through one webpage per accountNumber and extract from each.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get error?

Comment: Yes, it is giving me a yellow error on the `Sub FindData()` line for some reason.

Comment: what does the error message say??

Comment: Sorry - "Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: DavidZemens, did you have an answer there?

Comment: I may not be entirely clear about the `URL` goal: I have the table of `accountNumber`s. The `URL` for one account is the given `URL` with an `accountNumber` after the final `=`. I am trying to iterate through one webpage per `accountNumber` and extract from each. Does this clarify?

Comment: I think the root of my problem is in the `URL`. I have narrowed a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815916/concatenation-of-string-and-looped-value-with-vba

Answer (score 1):

```
Set dataSet = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;http://www.prad.org/CamaDisplay.aspx?OutputMode=Display&SearchType=RealEstate&ParcelID=" & Value, _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1"))
```

QueryTables needs to be properly referenced. You can use a sheet qualifier like :
Sheets("yourname").QueryTables or something.
 You can remove the dot too...

Comment: It's currently running now, which must be a good sign. I'll be sure to comment how it turns out for reference.

Comment: It seems to me that you may need to move your `Next Value` line to after the last `End With` if you want all those properties and the Refresh method to apply to each QueryTable, rather than just the last one...

Comment: It went to non-responsive after about 5 minutes, and went nowhere for another 5. I moved the `Next Value` as you suggested.

It ran two iterations, then gave "Run-time error '1004': Invalid Web Query

Comment: Could there be an issue with how I'm iterating through the URL strings? Or does this concatenation work by tacking on the individual `Value`s from `accountNumber` to the end of the `Connection` for each time it repeats?

Comment: If you have many web queries to run, that might be a problem. I don't use it a lot, but I'd say that making many connections and browsing via Excel isn't reliable(just a guess rather than a scientific statement). If you are opening one connection to a webquery with several values to the parameter, then you need to append them in the loop to a string. I'm unsure as to which is the case for you. I also don't see why there would ever be two iterations of that for each loop....

Comment: I guess you maybe need several values appended to the URL string. Then you need to build a string up differently, then execute the webquery. In which case, move the `Next Value' line back to where it was...

Comment: apparently the destination for the web query cannot be a different sheet than the sheet you are add it it to; which kinda makes sense. I am with MacroMarc though I am not fan of this methods. Try to use a HTTP Request that might give you want you need.

Comment: @MacroMarc, no, I'm not wanting to append several values to the end of the URL string and then query. I want to query once for each `value` I have, which will be at the URL ending with that `value`.

However, if this is just a bad idea altogether, what would be a better solution? The native HTTP Request only works one at a time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look into my code and see if this helps. I added a lot of comments to help you understand better the way the whole thing works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindData()

    Const strURL As String = "URL;http://www.prad.org/CamaDisplay.aspx?OutputMode=Display&SearchType=RealEstate&ParcelID="

    Dim shActive As Worksheet
    Dim shDestination As Worksheet
    Dim oQuery As QueryTable
    Dim rAccounts As Range
    Dim rAccount As Range


    'Initialize the variables
    Set shActive = ActiveSheet

    ' Note the "." in front of the ranges. That's how you use "With"
    With shActive
        Set rAccounts = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    ' Remove any old query otherwise they will pile up and slow down
    ' your workbook
    Call RemoveSheetQueries(shActive)


    ' Loop through the accounts and add the queries
    For Each rAccount In rAccounts
        Set oQuery = Nothing
        Set oQuery = shActive.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strURL & rAccount.Value, _
                                              Destination:=shActive.Range("A1"))

        ' Set the properties of the new query and eventually run it.
        With oQuery
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = "3"

            ' This last line will actually get the data
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next rAccount

End Sub



' Procedure to remove all old Queries
Sub RemoveSheetQueries(ByRef shToProcess As Worksheet)

    Dim lTotal As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lTotal = shToProcess.QueryTables.Count

    For i = lTotal To 1 Step -1
        shToProcess.QueryTables(i).Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I attempted your script, but it was unsuccessful - "Invalid Web Query" on the `QueryTables.Add()` section.

Comment: Try it now I added .QueryType = xlWebQuery to specify the type of query.

Comment: "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" with regards to the `.QueryType = xlWebQuery`