# Concatenation of string and looped value

Tags: string, excel, vba, concatenation

```
For Each Number In accountNumber
    Dim urlString As String
    urlString = "http://www.prad.org/CamaDisplay.aspx?OutputMode=Display&SearchType=RealEstate&ParcelID=" & accountNumber.Value
    Set dataSet = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;urlString, _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1"))
```

I am attempting to loop through the values `Number` in a column range `accountNumber`, adding them to the end of the `URL` given. This will ultimately visit multiple webpages, adding to the `QueryTables` each time.

Comment: you are adding `accountNumber.value` to the URL, not `Number`. Typo?

Comment: What error are you getting? Use fiddler and find out the exact url that is being sent. If it's not what you are expecting, then you know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for length :

From [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814016/debugging-a-querytables-add-script):

```
Sub FindData()

    Dim accountNumber As Range
    Set accountNumber = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Dim dataSet As QueryTable

    For Each Number In accountNumber
        Set dataSet = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;http://www.prad.org/CamaDisplay.aspx?OutputMode=Display&SearchType=RealEstate&ParcelID=" & Number.Value, _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")


        With dataSet
           .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
           .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
           .BackgroundQuery = True
           .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
           .WebTables = "3"
        End With

        With Application
             dataSet.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next Number
End Sub
```

You stated you were getting an Invalid Web Query. i don't think you need to append all values to one query. i think you need to run multiple queries, each with one value from the range.

I also think it's not going to be a good idea to have the same destination for all of them.

Comment: Is the code you provided running multiple queries then? I ran yours, got two outputs, and then it had another `Invalid Web Query`.

I don't have an issue changing the destination - I was mostly just trying to dump them somewhere so that I could then sort out which data I actually need from the HTML scrape and write a cell formula in Sheet1 for the cells where I need the data to ultimately end up.